# Using SQL JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've never used joins before, but I've been reading for the past couple of hours but can't seem to get things to work how I'd like them to.

I have 2 tables, in different databases, I need to return data from both of them in one query.

I have a table called `Player` in the database `kal_db`, and one called `Login` in the database `kal_auth`

I need to return the 'Country' field from `Login` where `Player.UID = Login.UID`, aswell as all the data from the `Player` table.

I've tried to do it many ways, and just can't make it work.

Any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, l.Country
FROM kal_db.dbo.Player as p
INNER JOIN kal_Auth.dbo.Login as l
ON p.UID = l.UID
```

I'd also recommend giving this article a good read:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

It is the best explanation of the various types of joins I've seen and it goes into a bit of the syntax.

Comment: this solves my problem completely, and that post opened my mind to this field alot more. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select l.Country, p.* 
from kal_auth.dbo.Login l 
join kal_db.dbo.Player p 
on p.UID = l.UID
```

Answer (score 2):

> select l.Country,p.* from
>   kal_db..Player p join kal_auth..Login
>   l on l.UID=p.UID

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
          Select l.Country
          from kal_db.dbo.Player p 
          Inner Join 
          kal_Auth.dbo.Login l
          on p.UID = l.UID
```